# Kindle Cloud Reader app search feature wacky behavior

Tags: kindle-cloud-reader

I search a Kindle e-book using the Kindle Cloud Reader app, for example I type **imper** and it finds a number of entries containing the word **imperative** where that word is bolded and underlined. But if I search for **imperative** or even for **impera** there are zero hits. What is going on there?

Comment: Okay, how about other words in the same book?  Please see [ask] and [edit] the question to include additional details that will help readers understand the problem and how it relates to the web app.

Comment: Just downloaded a Windows desktop Kindle Reader version and tried searching the same book. Works much better. So the issue is with the Chromebook version of the app.  I suspect a bug in the autcomplete code. Oh, how I hate that feature. Stupid time-waster masquerading as helpful cleverness.

Comment: @TimR any relevant info should be edited into the question not posted as comments.  I'm glad you found a solution.